# Excel VBA Splitting Line of Code - ADO Connection

Tags: excel, vba, ado

I have some code that takes data from an xl worksheet and sends it to a SQL server table.

All works fine until I try and split the code into separate lines. Have tried all sorts of things but nothing seems to work.

The line I am trying to split it

```
            "values ('" & strFirstName & "', '" & strLastName & " ')"
```

Thanks.

Code is as follows:

Sub TEST_UPLOAD()
'TRUSTED CONNECTION
On Error GoTo errH

```
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strPath As String
Dim intImportRow As Integer
Dim strFirstName, strLastName As String

Dim server, username, password, table, database As String


With Sheets("Sheet1")

        server = "QQQQQQ"
        table = "test1"
        database = "QQQQDB"


        If con.State <> 1 Then

            con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & server & ";Initial Catalog=" & database & ";Integrated Security=SSPI;"
            'con.Open

        End If
        'this is the TRUSTED connection string

        Set rs.ActiveConnection = con

        'delete all records first if checkbox checked
        'If .CheckBox1 Then
            con.Execute "delete from test1"
        'End If

        'set first row with records to import
        'you could also just loop thru a range if you want.
        intImportRow = 2

        Do Until .Cells(intImportRow, 1) = ""
            strFirstName = .Cells(intImportRow, 1)
            strLastName = .Cells(intImportRow, 2)

            'insert row into database
            con.Execute "insert into test1 (firstname, lastname) " & _
            "values ('" & strFirstName & "', '" & strLastName & " ')"

            intImportRow = intImportRow + 1
        Loop

        MsgBox "Done importing", vbInformation

        con.Close
        Set con = Nothing

End With
```

Exit Sub

Comment: What do you mean, "split"  Do either firstname or lastname contain ' ?

Comment: Split the code over separate lines. For example:  I want to split this line ... "values ('" & strFirstName & "', '" & strLastName & " ')" into 2 parts on 2 lines. The reason as to why is because the real query I want to use is very large.  Thanks

Comment: `"values ('" & strFirstName &  _ "', '" & strLastName & " ')"  Like the line above?

Comment: That's the line I want to split. I would Ideally like ["values ('" & strFirstName &] on one line and  ["', '" & strLastName & " ')"] on the next. Square brackets just for illustration. I realise normally would put [ & _ ] at the end of a line but this doesn't seem to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid mixing data with code by using a parameterized query.

```vb
Sub TEST_UPLOAD()
  
    Const server = "QQQQQQ"
    Const database = "QQQQDB"
    Const table = "test1"

    ' sql with placeholders ? for values
    Const SQL = " INSERT INTO " & table & _
                " (firstname, lastname) " & _
                " VALUES (?,?)"

    Dim con As New ADODB.Connection, sCon As String
    Dim intImportRow As Integer

    sCon = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & server & _
            ";Initial Catalog=" & database & _
            ";Integrated Security=SSPI;"

    If con.State <> 1 Then
        con.Open sCon
    End If
  
    ' prepare sql with parameters
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
       .ActiveConnection = con
       .CommandText = SQL
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50) ' varchar(50)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P2", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50)
    End With

    ' clear table
    con.Execute "DELETE FROM " & table

    intImportRow = 2
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        ' execute sql with parameter values
        Do Until .Cells(intImportRow, 1) = ""
            cmd.Parameters(0) = .Cells(intImportRow, 1) ' firstname
            cmd.Parameters(1) = .Cells(intImportRow, 2) ' lastname
            cmd.Execute
            intImportRow = intImportRow + 1
        Loop
    End With
    MsgBox intImportRow - 2 & " rows imported", vbInformation

    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I'll have a look at this.

Comment: This worked so much better than my original method. Have now implemented where I update a table with 100+ columns.  Many thanks  Andrew